# using string for group change of a property for specific OLEObjects in sheets

Tags: string, excel, object, vba

In my VBA project I used following to apply group changed for clearing Activx Control box having "item" in the beginning of their object name. it worked fine.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Const Connamepfix As String = "item"
Dim obj As OLEObject

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(7)
With ws
    For Each obj In .OLEObjects
       If Left(obj.Name, 4) = Connamepfix Then
            obj.Object.Clear
       End If
    Next obj
End With
```

when i tried to use the same code for seting proprty of ListFillRange for the above group of activex control I got no error but the property remains clear.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Const Connamepfix As String = "item"
Dim obj As OLEObject

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(7)    
With ws
    For Each obj In .OLEObjects
         If Left(obj.Name, 4) = Connamepfix Then
             obj.Object.ListFillRnage = "name_ac"
         End If
    Next obj
End With
```

when I manually put name_ac in property sheet of obect it worked fine. would you please show a way for mass edit of this property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `=` in to the name when you set the ListFillRange

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Const Connamepfix As String = "item"
Dim obj As OLEObject

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(7)    
With ws
    For Each obj In .OLEObjects
         If Left(obj.Name, 4) = Connamepfix Then
             obj.Object.ListFillRange = "=name_ac"  ''=' added here.
         End If
    Next obj
End With
```

I presume that this name_ac is a named range?

Comment: true, name_ac is a named range. I have the problem again. the box is not populated.

Answer (score 0):

**ListFillRange** is the property of the **OleObject** object.  Try...

```
obj.ListFillRange = "=name_ac"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this ain't worked too. i think the only way is to type one by one!

Comment: i get no error but nume_ac not put in listfillrange property